# assigning values to characters in java

Tags: java

i have sequence like 
A C T G -
- C A G T
G - - C A
and i stored in a text file.
if there is - in file i want to assign value 0 and show 0 instead of i
and same for G,A,T,C to 1,2,3,4

```
import java.io.*;
public class file
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
   {
      FileReader fr=new FileReader("TESTDATA_HPV_34_1.txt");
      BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
      String s;
     while((s=br.readLine())!=null)
      {
        System.out.println(s);

      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Use a Map to map the Key (`{A, B, C, D}`) and the Value (`{1, 2, 3, 4}`), then poll it every time you have a character.

Comment: Not related but: don't forget to close stuff when you're done with it (in this case you're forgetting `br.close()`). Keep in mind that throwing `Exception` from `main()` will not close your resources, leaving them in an undefined (possibly corrupt) state. You probably don't want this as you don't want to lose data. Best practice for this situation is `try{//doyourstruffhere}finally{//closeyourstuffhere}`

Comment: `s.replace('-','0').replace('G','1').replace('A','2').replace('T','3').replace('C','4')`

Answer (score 2):

You can use String's `replace()` instance method.

```
String newString = s.replace("-", "0");
```

You can also chain them together.

```
newString = s.replace("G","1").replace("A","2").replace("T","3").replace("C","4");
```

`replace` returns a new string with the replacement because String is an immutable class.

If your test data is very large (and I mean very very large), it may be worth writing your own replace method that loops through the string only once and replaces each charactor. Test and see if there is a performance issue with just using a few replaces.

Comment: ohh, I thought the guy wants to prints each character, your answer is correct

Comment: how to write that replace method

Comment: @user1776340: arshajii provides a pretty good implementation for a quicker single loop version.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a map as follows:

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(5);
map.put('-', 0);
map.put('G', 1);
map.put('A', 2);
map.put('T', 3);
map.put('C', 4);
```

Now, you can do something along the lines of:

```
String dna = "A C T G - - C A G T G - - C A";

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(dna.length());
for (int i = 0; i < dna.length(); i++) {
    char c = dna.charAt(i);

    if (map.containsKey(c))
        result.append(map.get(c));
    else
        result.append(c);
}

System.out.println(result);
```

```
2 4 3 1 0 0 4 2 1 3 1 0 0 4 2
```

Answer (score 0):

readLine gives you a line as String

0) create a map with keys G,A,T,C and values 1,2,3,4

1) get character array from the String line

2) create a variable charVal

3) iterate through the character array

4) for each character, initialize charVal to 0, get the value from map for that char, assign it to charVal

5) print charVal

P.S.: close resources properly

Answer (score 0):

As Sotirios said, use a `Map` for binding keys to their corresponding values. You can iterate that `Map` and apply `replace()` to the String you have (sorry for the poor formatting):

```
import java.io.*;
public class file
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
   {
      Map<Character, Character> replacements = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
      replacements.put('-', '0');
      replacements.put('G', '1');
      // ....
      FileReader fr=new FileReader("TESTDATA_HPV_34_1.txt");
      BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
      String s;
      while((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
          for ( Map.Entry<Character, Character> entry : replacements.entrySet() ) {
              s = s.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
          }
        System.out.println(s);

      }

   }
}
```

As Cemafor said, if you're concerned about performance, then maybe you should use [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for making all replacements at once.

Comment: hey i got it thnx lot